# How to create multiple shares from Debian using NFS that can be mounted in windows 7

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

I have a Debian machine that I'm using as a media server/file server. It's running Debian wheezy.

I have a raid volume i've set up using mdadm.  All working fine.

I've set up some primitive FTP access to the folders i need to - again so far so good.

But i've come to start providing access to the NAS using NFS and it's giving me a bit of a headache.

I've created two mount points which are mounted (using --bind) to where the files are.

`/dev/md0  mounted to /media/vol1`

`/mnt/media mounted to /media/vol1/media (using --bind)`

`/mnt/docs mounted to /media/vol1/docs (using --bind)`

i've added the following to the `export` file and restarted `exportfs -a`

`/mnt/media 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`

`/mnt/docs 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash)`

From Windows 7 - command line

`mount -u:user -p:pass mynas:/mnt/media *` doesn't work NETMSG 2 I think

However this does:
`mount -u:user -p:pass mynas:/mnt *` although the folder is empty.

On certain occasions when i've been playing about with this, the NFS client in windows actually BSDOs windows.  It feels like permissions, but wondered whether someone could give me a hand?

many thanks (in advance)

sam

Comment: First, a media server appears to a home-related subject, which makes this off-topic here (please see our [FAQ]). I wonder though why you want to use NFS instead of Samba, which was designed to communicate with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I have found Windows implementations of NFS to be very sensitive and somewhat unstable.  You might try a different NFS client from another vendor to see if this improves your stability.

It might be a pain, but have you thought of using Samba to do the windows side sharing?

Comment: thanks for feedback / answer both of you. just looking into samba now :)